# i am getting this error although its working but its gives warning

Tags: php

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce_cms_tutorial\register.php on line 172
}elseif ($row_register['email'] != $email && $password == $confirm_password) {

Comment: Seeing this small piece of code and the error, the most likely scenario is that the variable $row_register is null at this point. However, to be sure you could try something like:
``dd($row_register);exit();`` and see what it evaluates to.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with a null array element:
You have **2 options**:

1. Use isset($arr['element'))
2. Use @ with array like @$arr['element'];

   if(isset($row_register['email']){
   // Enter your code here
   }

Answer (score 1):

This happens because $row_register is not null but the index 'email' does not exist (yet). because you are using newer version of PHP You will need to add the following:

```
isset($row_register['email'])
```

Comment: thank you so much , i appreciated your effort to give answer to my question . It's working i am new to PHP thanks for your help